# Trouble with JSON parsing in swift 1.2

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

**Trouble with JSON parsing in swift 1.2**

I have an issue with the JSON parsing, i am not getting the correct  data response for my parameters. i have been stuck on the issue for quite some time now. i don’t know how to fix it. i am new to iOS development. also i haven’t used any third party library.[Don’t know how to use them]

**I am getting the right response for my very first iteration but for the next iteration results of previous iteration is added along with the new results. Like that each loop result is ended up with the results of previous iteration**

**My JSON SAMPLE.**[can provide link, please let me know]

```html
struct AssetItems {
    
    var Name:String
    var Desc:String
    var Image:String
    var entityId:String
    
    var aFileType:String
    var aFileSize:String
    var aFileCreatedDate:String
    var aFileRevisionDate:String
    var aFileModifiedDate:String
    var aProductName:String
    var aVersion:String
    var aAssetType:String
    var aIsFolder:String
    
    init(assetName:String,assetDescription:String,assetImage:String,entityId:String,FileType:String,FileSize:String,FileCretedDate:String,FileReveisionDate:String,FileModifiedDate:String,ProductName:String,Version:String,AssetType:String,IsFolder:String) {
        
        
        
        self.Name = assetName
        self.Desc = assetDescription
        self.Image = assetImage
        self.entityId = entityId
        self.aFileType = FileType
        self.aFileSize = FileSize
        self.aFileCreatedDate = FileCretedDate
        self.aFileRevisionDate = FileReveisionDate
        self.aFileModifiedDate = FileModifiedDate
        self.aProductName = ProductName
        self.aVersion = Version
        self.aAssetType = AssetType
        self.aIsFolder = IsFolder
    }
}



struct AssetModel {
    var aName:String
    var aDesc:String
    var aCount:String
    var aEntityId:String
    var items:[AssetItems]
    
    init(rackName:String,rackDescription:String,totalNoAssets:String,EntityId:String,rackItems:[AssetItems]) {
        self.aName = rackName
        self.aDesc = rackDescription
        self.aCount = totalNoAssets
        self.aEntityId = EntityId
        self.items = rackItems
    }
    
}

  
var assetData:Array<AssetModel> = Array<AssetModel>()
var assetContents:Array<AssetItems> = Array<AssetItems>()
```

**THIS IS HOW I AM PARSING JSON**

```html
 func get_data_from_Url(url:String) {
        
        
        let url = NSURL(string: url)
        var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
        
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content_Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        
        
        var responseError : NSError?
        var response : NSURLResponse?
        
        var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &responseError)
        
        if(urlData != nil) {
            
            var responseData:NSString = NSString(data: urlData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
            var err:NSError?
            if (res.statusCode == 200)
            {
                var parseError: NSError?
                let json:AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &err) as AnyObject!
                if (parseError == nil) // no error while parsing
                {
                    if let Asset_list = json as? NSArray
                    {
                    for (var i = 0; i < Asset_list.count ; i++ )
                    {
                    if let Asset_obj = Asset_list[i] as? NSDictionary
                    {
                    if let AssetGroupName = Asset_obj["Name"] as? String
                    {
                    if let AssetGroupDescription = Asset_obj["Description"] as? String
                    {
                    if let entityId = Asset_obj["EntityId"] as? String
                    {
                    if let totalAssets = Asset_obj["_NoOfAssets"] as? String
                    {
                    if let items = Asset_obj["Items"] as? NSArray
                    {
                    for (var j=0 ; j < items.count; j++)
                    {
                    if let asset_items = items[j] as? NSDictionary
                    {
                    if let AbsolutePath = asset_items["AbsolutePath"] as? String
                    {
                    if let Description = asset_items["_Description"] as? String
                    {
                    if let Name = asset_items["_Name"] as? String {
                    if let entityId = asset_items["EntityId"] as? String
                    {
                    if let FileType = asset_items["_FileType"] as? String
                    {
                    if let FileSize = asset_items["_FileSize"] as? String
                    {
                    if let FileCreatedDate = asset_items["CreatedDate"] as? String
                    {
                    if let FileModifiedDate = asset_items["ModifiedDate"] as? String
                    {
                    if let RevisionDate = asset_items["RevisionDate"] as? String
                    {
                    if let productName = asset_items["ProductName"] as? String
                    {
                    if let version = asset_items["Version"] as? String
                    {
                    if let AssetType = asset_items["_AssetType"] as? String
                    {
                    if let isFolder = asset_items["IsFolder"] as? String
                    {
                        
                                                                                                                    
                var add = AssetItems(assetName: Name, assetDescription: Description, assetImage: AbsolutePath, entityId: entityId, FileType: FileType, FileSize: FileSize, FileCretedDate: FileCreatedDate, FileReveisionDate: RevisionDate, FileModifiedDate: FileModifiedDate, ProductName: productName, Version: version, AssetType: AssetType, IsFolder: isFolder)
                    assetContents.append(add)

                        }
                        }
                        }
                        }
                        }
                       }
                    }
                    }
                   }
                }
                }
                                                                    
                }
                }
                        
                }
                        
                }
            var add_it = AssetModel(rackName: AssetGroupName, rackDescription: AssetGroupDescription, totalNoAssets: totalAssets, EntityId: entityId, rackItems: assetContents)
                assetData.append(add_it)
                        
                        }
                    }
                                            
                    }
                        
                    }
                        
                    }
                        
                    }
                    }
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        
        
        do_table_refresh()
    }

func do_table_refresh()
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
            {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                
        })
        
        return
    }
```

**My Output**

**Please some one help me fix this,** Any suggestion will also do.

**THANKS**

Comment: If you are new to Swift don't start with an outdated version of the language. The most recent version is 2.2 and Swift 3 will be released in a few weeks. And consider to conform to the naming convention: variable names start always with a lowercase letter and no php/javascript underscore separators.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I Started this project long back, now i  cant change the entire thing...

Comment: You can't or you don't want ? ;-)

Comment: @vadian: No sir ,it is just too much work around. In future  i am going to use latest version for sure.

Comment: You might consider sending your code to thedailywtf.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special thanks to @SMi, With his GuidLines i was able to solve my issue.
I knew that i had to clear the inner array at the end of the loop[But,didn't knew how to clear that.]

```
 var add_it = AssetModel(rackName: AssetGroupName, rackDescription: AssetGroupDescription, totalNoAssets: totalAssets, EntityId: entityId, rackItems: assetContents)
       assetData.append(add_it)
assetContents.removeAll()
```

All i had to do is use the **.removeAll()** method to clear the **assetContents** Array.